# Segmentation fault error when training a model on WML

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I am trying to train a model on Watson machine learning platform and I get this error when I run the command line :

```
bx ml train model.zip training-runs.yml
```

The error:

```
....
[--LOGS]      training-bEgMj0wiR: You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 18.1 is available.

[--LOGS]      training-bEgMj0wiR: You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

[--LOGS]      training-bEgMj0wiR: /usr/local/bin/train.sh: line 38:    48 Segmentation fault      python3 train.py 2>&1

[--LOGS]      training-bEgMj0wiR: Training exited with error code 139

[--LOGS]      training-bEgMj0wiR: Failed: learner_exit_code: 139
```

You can notice that it is mentioning that the command line lunched is:

```
python3 train.py
```

Looks like an error linked to the machine where the model is running. When I run the training on my local machine by setting the local environment variables, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the WML service is hosted in the United states `us-south` and the data is stored in Cloud Object Storage in `London`, so I changed the WML service to London and the error disappeared.

I'm not sure what is the relationship between them... but just in case somebody is having the same issue.